# change windows boot order from within ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

So I just switched over to ubuntu. I used easyBCD to choose between linux mint and windows 7 before the switch. I now have it set up for a dual boot. When the installation was finished, I logged into windows and updated the boot information in easyBCD. I deleted the Linux Mint option, and added Ubuntu. When I restarted my computer, my options were Linux Mint and Ubuntu, both of which bring me to the Ubuntu GRUB loader.

EasyBCD deleted the wrong option, and now I can't get back into Windows. If I choose "Ubuntu," it takes me to the GRUB loader, and the Windows 7 option at the bottom of that just throws me back to the easyBCD menu. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this without completely reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download Grub Cusomizer from the Software Centre, this gives you the option to Reorder and customize your Grub to how you want it.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. The grub loader is fine. What happens is when you try to boot windows, it has it's own grub-like menu, which only includes ubuntu now.

Comment: if you have a Windows install CD, boot with this and try and repair it through this.